# How tensors ranks can be dynamic in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training an image classifier using tf-slim library. The training looks good until a certain point where I have a dimension error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scripts/eval.py", line 190, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "scripts/eval.py", line 186, in main
    timeout=None)
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/evaluation.py", line 296, in evaluation_loop
    timeout=timeout)
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/evaluation.py", line 455, in evaluate_repeatedly
    '%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime()))
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 521, in __exit__
    self._close_internal(exception_type)
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 556, in _close_internal
    self._sess.close()
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 791, in close
    self._sess.close()
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 888, in close
    ignore_live_threads=True)
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 238, in _run
    enqueue_callable()
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1063, in _single_operation_run
    target_list_as_strings, status, None)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
File "/home/tmattio/Envs/tf1.2rc2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: input must be 4-dimensional[1,1,1000,823,3]
        [[Node: eval_image/ResizeArea = ResizeArea[T=DT_FLOAT, align_corners=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](eval_image/ExpandDims/_3123, eval_image/ResizeArea/size)]]
        [[Node: eval_image/ResizeArea/_3125 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_85_eval_image/ResizeArea", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

How is it possible for the training input to change its rank?

I use the DataProvider API to get the input:

```
provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(
    dataset,
    num_readers=FLAGS.num_readers,
    common_queue_capacity=20 * FLAGS.batch_size,
    common_queue_min=10 * FLAGS.batch_size)
[image, label] = provider.get(['image', 'label'])
```

Then process it:

```
image = preprocess_for_train(image, train_image_size, train_image_size, None)
```

And finally run the training:

```
slim.learning.train(
    train_tensor,
    logdir=FLAGS.train_dir,
    master=FLAGS.master,
    is_chief=(FLAGS.task == 0),
    init_fn=_get_init_fn(),
    summary_op=summary_op,
    number_of_steps=FLAGS.max_number_of_steps,
    log_every_n_steps=FLAGS.log_every_n_steps,
    save_summaries_secs=FLAGS.save_summaries_secs,
    save_interval_secs=FLAGS.save_interval_secs,
    sync_optimizer=optimizer if FLAGS.sync_replicas else None)
```

Here is the code where the error seems to be raised from:

```
distorted_image = tf.expand_dims(distorted_image, 0)
distorted_image = tf.image.resize_area(distorted_image, [height, width],
                                       align_corners=False)
distorted_image = tf.squeeze(distorted_image, [0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
distorted_image = tf.expand_dims(distorted_image, 0)
```

will add an additional rank converting your tensor from

- [1,1000,823,3] your original 1 image of 1000x823 pixels and 3 colors

to

- [1,1,1000,823,3] having 1 additional rank.

For more information on how [tf.expand_dims works go here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims)

Then the next line **tf.image.resize_area** throws the error, because the tensor has a rank of 5 and tf.image.resize_area can only handle 4 ranks.

Comment: My original image is a 3-D tensor. If it was a 4-D tensor, the graph could not be launched, but I am able to run the training for about 20mins before the error is raised.

Comment: How many epochs or images are processed in the 20 mins before the error is raised?

Comment: if in one set of calls you pass data like **feed-dict={ images : list_containing_one_image }** and then later after 20 min of processing and possibly in a test loop you pass data differently like **feed-dict={ images : [ list_containing_one_image ] }** then your graph will not complain until it hits **tf.image.resize_area**

Comment: I process half of the first epoch. The data is coming from a tf-slim DataProvider only, so all the inputs are supposed to have the same format, right?